# Sign out error Cloud Firestore. The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter app where I have signed in users successfully and no errors are thrown up. But, when I attempt FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut() in one of my buttons, it signs the user out but throws up this error. I have attached my cloud firestore rules below.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /merchants/{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /all_merchants/{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /Types/{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /Promotions/{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /search_types/{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }

    
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      
      match /{document=**}{
        allow read, update, create, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
    
     match /users/{email} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.token.email == email;
      allow create: if request.auth.token.email != null;
      
      match /{document=**}{
        allow read, update, create, delete: if request.auth.token.email == email;
      }
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

(edit): My Flutter code for the button is as below:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SignOut extends StatelessWidget {

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
          setState(() {
                auth.signOut();
               });
            },
      child: ListTile(
        dense: true,
        leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app, color: Colors.red[600], size: 25,),
        title: Text('Sign Out',
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.black, size: 19,),
      ),
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think that error doesn't has anything to do with security rules.  Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and what you're doing that causes the error.

Comment: Added it! Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happens because somewhere in your app you’re probably still keeping stream subscriptions to some Firestore queries that aren’t accessible after you sign out because you’re correctly preventing it with the rules.

Check your project code and look for any eventual subscriptions that aren’t being canceled before the user signs out.

Comment: I have this case in my project. I was wondering if it is necessary to cancel all the subscriptions even though the rules will no longer allow the reads? In my case, a firestore stream (only allowed to read by authenticated user) is being listened to by a `StreamBuilder`. So on sign-out, I see this error rightly. Does the stream still try to unsuccessfully read the changes even after the error? Should the subscription (started internally by `StreamBuilder`) be cancelled on sign-out? If so, how can we do it?

Comment: Yes. That `StreamBuilder` is within a widget which is automatically disposed with it. You need to make sure that you don't have active widgets that rely in an invalid `StreamBuilder` if you sign out — this means that you need to dispose those widgets before signing out.

Comment: Yes, there is another place too where I have subscribed to a firestore stream (not with `StreamBuilder`). But I am also `cancel`ing the stream before sign-out, but I still see Firestore's `permission-denied` error immediately after sign-out. Don't know why.