# Debug [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: firebase, macos, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-file

I use Flutter, Timer and Firebase/Firestore.batch to do something like this sample code to save data periodically on Mac.
https://github.com/tomoyuki28jp/flutterfire_scheduled_batch_write_sample2

When I run my app for few days, I get this error randomly:

```
flutter: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
flutter:
#0      MethodChannelWriteBatch.commit
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_write_batch.dart:51
<asynchronous suspension>
```

- After hot reloading, it start working again.
- Background task keep throwing this error until restarting or reloading my app
- While a background task is throwing this error, I can still successfully save firestore data  by using my app UI manually.

How can I investigate the cause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign out error Cloud Firestore. The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922374/sign-out-error-cloud-firestore-the-caller-does-not-have-permission-to-execute-t)

Comment: Please include the code you're having difficulty with in the question. If you delete that link in the future, it would make the question useless to future readers. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Roger Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Have you figured out a solution? I'm having this issue as well.

Comment: @31Carlton7 Unfortunately, no :(
I've been struggling for a long time. If you figure out a solution, please let me know. If you can create a sample code which reproduce the issue, please open a github issue and let me know.

Comment: @Tom I wonder why firestore can't do a query like this. For a company like Google, I'm surprised that there's only 8-10 querying methods. I had to restructure my code in the end, and I'm having to store duplicate data inside the database. This should be addressed.

Comment: I've created a github issue. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6898

Answer (score 0):

User credentials *do* expire over time - hot reloading likely re-establishes the Auth session.  It is known that Auth needs to be re-established periodically - Firestore is NOT really intended as a permanent connection.  Your code needs to be able to respond to changes in Auth state (there is a library function to Listen to Auth events), and respond accordingly - including re-authorizing if that's your intent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know firebase tokens are valid only for one hour. But the wired thing is the error occurs randomly sometimes later like few days after starting my app.